# Trying to connect to a database through R

Tags: r, database, rmariadb

```
+                 user = 'sql5404117',
+                 password = "*******",
+                 dbname = 'sql504117',
+                 host = 'sql5.freemysqlhosting.net',
+                 port = 3306)
Error: Failed to connect: Access denied for user 'sql5404117'@'%' to database 'sql504117'
```

everytime I try to connect to the database I keep getting this error.

Comment: Ummmm ... talk to your DBA. There is no programming that can fix a user authentication issue (short of "breaking in", not a topic for discussion here, and I think not what you're asking).

Comment: Are you able to connect via other methods, not in R?